# Login.xib then launch mainmenu.xib XCode OS X

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

What is the step by step guide to show a login.xib for the user then based on the result show the mainmenu.xib?

I tried to change the login.xib and change the "Main Interface" in "General" project settings to it but when it loads I get:

```
Could not connect the action loginButton: to target of class NSApplication
```

What have I done wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

File's Owner for your login.xib is what class?  That's the cause of the error message.  You need a custom controller class that loads and owns that Nib.  For MainMenu.xib, that's the application delegate if you have a single-coordinator app.  I'd recommend keeping that setup.  Login.xib needs a NSWindowController subclass to own and load it.  You'd create that controller in applicationDidFinishLaunching.  The controller will load the Nib and display the window.

But some further comments:

In a single-coordinator application, XCode sets up a custom app delegate class that owns the MainMenu.xib window -- the MainMenu.xib Nib is loaded in NSApplicationMain because its listed in the Info.plist as NSMainNibFile

So, you could try making login.xib your NSMainNibFile like you've discussed, and that would be owned by your application delegate.

You could then load MainMenu.xib with a custom window controller when the user logs in.  If the user logs out, you can redisplay the login screen.  The main menu won't be visible when the login screen is visible because it's not part of the login.xib and hasn't been loaded.

What I'd stringly recommend, though, is keeping mainmenu.xib as the NSMainNibFile, and having custom window controllers for login.xib AND your user interface that's presented after a login.